# Getting Activity instance by name(if is running)

Tags: java, android

A have an application with the long-running task. The task object is safely moved out to the Application object. But still, I need update a UI. So far, the task is really long-running, so the user can go to another activity and the current one may be destroyed, but the task will continue working. 
And now, after the task was done, I want to change the UI on the activity. But this may be a new instance of the activity, or the activity may be destroyed. But if it is alive(no matter which instance) I want to make this change. This is a pseudo-code what I need:

```
MyActivity act = SomeActivityManager.get(MyActivity.class.name());
if(act == null) {
// the activity is destroyed, no action needed, 
// on next creating all UI changes will be in place
} else {
     act.drawRedLine(); // custom method of my activity
}
```

And I prefer android-sdk based solution (still I can go with `WeakHashMap` with all activities in Application object, but this is definitely dirty way with potential problems);

Comment: Why not host the long-running-task in a service then updates the Activity ones you are back?

Comment: For updating activity, I need a reference for it. I cannot keep a reference to it because the system may recreate activity and reference will be invalid, also I will fall in a memory leak. So I need a real active reference. That's the question about.

Comment: Preferably once the Activity is not currently visible you should stop your rendering because it can sometimes create a flickering effect in the current visible activity (much worst if that current activity is also animating). Hosting the state or your mathimatical logic/computation can be trivial but beneficial in the end since you can re-render the last value comming from your host during onStart(), in that time you can obtain back the Activity reference.

Comment: '''but beneficial in the end since you can re-render the last value coming from your host during onStart()''' - how about a case when second(the same but new) activity is created white result is not ready?

Comment: Remember I suggest hosting it in Service *it does not know* anything about the activity if it is the same instance as it talks before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way, but you could use an Intent, sent by your long-running-task with something like

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendIntent(new Intent("DrawRedLine"));`

and receive it in your Activity with a BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver(){  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //update your activity
    }
};
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("DrawRedLine"));
```

Register it this way in `onCreate` and unregister it in `onDestroy` with

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(br);
```

Comment: Possible answer, technically quite close to a variant with `WeakHashMap`, but safer. Any case still interesting in some Activity manager. This variant has a bit bad side because all my intent filters look like global variables. So I must be careful with naming and keep this these filters under control. My application has a lot of such operations and calls.